# Implementing XMLRPC

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm developing a custom blog system like wordpress.

The problem is that I didn't understand what the <link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" /> is for, and whether it is necessary for better page rank.

If it is necessary, is it possible to implement it in my custom website? how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-RPC is a way to send data (as xml files) to wordpress. For example you could remotely publish posts using an offline blog editor.

Personally I don't think it is really useful and it's definitely not necessary.